# Silverlight White text with Black Border?

Tags: silverlight

I saw that you can do a dropshadow: http://pagebrooks.com/archive/2009/03/30/easy-drop-shadows-on-text-in-silverlight-3.aspx

Can you also do a text border, like white colored text with a black border around each glyph?

My problem is actually this:

In our web application, a user can pick ANY color for a background, and we're going to put their username in that background. How can I write the username text so that it is visible?

Answer (score 2):

You have to be willing to use paths instead of fonts, but there are tools that can automate this for you, such as this: http://www.codeplex.com/sltext

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but you can adjust your shadowdepth to 0 so so it's no distance from the letters. Bit of a hack but you can get some nice blending effects

[alt text http://www.blackspike.com/jing/textOutline.png](http://www.blackspike.com/jing/textOutline.png)

Comment: Looks cool, but that's white text with a gray outline, and I need black.