# Inner Shadow Text with Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, shadows

I've been trying for the last several hours to find a way to create inner shadows for text. Essentially I want to create effects similar to this in Silverlight:
[Inner text shadow with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889501/inner-text-shadow-with-css)

I was able to find some leads in this website (the closest seeming to be this question): [Silverlight White text with Black Border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901835/silverlight-white-text-with-black-border)
But nothing really came very close.

The only instances I have found were only to add inner shadows to rectangles and shapes. But the same method would not work on text as far as I am aware.

Does anyone have a way of achieving the effect either through xaml or code? I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this to get the outline (Path) of the text in Silverlight](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/10/Using-Text-Outlines-in-Silverlight.html)

Then, if you have the path, you can use [this to generate a inner shadow](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/innershadows.aspx)

Comment: Not going to work for silverlight since it doesn't support visual brush.

Comment: @Denis, Did you read the article? There is a special reference to how to do this in Silverlight scroll down to "Inner Shadows with the Clip property".